# react check array values based on specific keys returning true/false if values found

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to figure out how to do this but can't seem to wrap my head around it..

I have an address object

```
 const obj = {
   "address_type":"Home",
   "country":"US",
   "addressLine1":"123  Any Street",
   "addressLine2":"",
   "city":"Any Town",
   "state":"Indiana",
   "state_code":"IN",
   "zip":"46220-4466",
   "phone":"6715551313",
   "mobile_number":"",
   "extn":"",
   "fax":"",
   "county_name":"MyCounty"
}
```

I want to check for any key that has a value but only specific keys

```
const objProps = ["addressLine1","addressLine2","city","state_code","zip","county_name"];
```

I want to check all keys in objProps against my address object and if any one of them contains a value return true (doesn't matter if its 1 or all 6).. If all keys don't contain a value then return false (Sometimes I will get an address object that has all null values)

I've tried various ways to accomplish this but have failed in each one.

The variation I am working on now is using reduce. While it doesn't meet my needs I thought I could check the resulting array and if length was greater than 0 than I have my answer..

Work-in-progress:

```
function hasAddressData(obj: any) {
        const objProps = ["addressLine1","addressLine2","city","state_code","zip","county_name"];
        const keysWithData = objProps.reduce((accumulator, key) => {
            const propExistsOnObj = obj.hasOwnProperty(key);
            let keyHasData = [];
            if (obj[key].length > 0 ) {
                keyHasData = obj[key]
            }

            if (!propExistsOnObj) {
                accumulator.push(key);
            } else if (keyHasData) {
                const equalValueKeyIndex = accumulator.indexOf(key);
                accumulator.splice(equalValueKeyIndex, 1);
            }
            return accumulator;
        });

        return keysWithData;
    }
```

The above is messed up I know and doesn't work..  Just learning this stuff..  anyone have a suggestion or comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function checkKeys(target, props) {
  return props.some((prop) => {
    return target.hasOwnProperty(prop) && target[prop];
  });
}
```

Explanation: `some` iterates through the props you want to check, returning `true` immediately when one is found (i.e. the callback returns `true`).  If no props are found (i.e. no callback returns `true`), `some` returns `false`.

`hasOwnProperty` ensures that you are only checking properties on `target`, and not looking up the prototype chain.  `target[prop]` checks for a truthy value.  You may need to modify this last check if you're going to be handling values other than strings.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation..  I have yet to use "some"..  You have taught me something today..  I can work with this and expand upon it :)

Answer (score 1):

Check that `.some` of the `objProps`, when looked up on the `obj`, contain a value. (Either with `Boolean` or by comparing against `''`)

```js
const obj = {
   "address_type":"Home",
   "country":"US",
   "addressLine1":"123  Any Street",
   "addressLine2":"",
   "city":"Any Town",
   "state":"Indiana",
   "state_code":"IN",
   "zip":"46220-4466",
   "phone":"6715551313",
   "mobile_number":"",
   "extn":"",
   "fax":"",
   "county_name":"MyCounty"
}
const objProps = ["addressLine1","addressLine2","city","state_code","zip","county_name"];

const somePopulated = objProps.some(prop => obj[prop]);
// or prop => obj[prop] !== ''
console.log(somePopulated);
```

```js
const obj = {
   "address_type":"Home",
   "country":"US",
   "addressLine1":"",
   "addressLine2":"",
   "city":"",
   "state":"Indiana",
   "state_code":"",
   "zip":"",
   "phone":"6715551313",
   "mobile_number":"",
   "extn":"",
   "fax":"",
   "county_name":""
}
const objProps = ["addressLine1","addressLine2","city","state_code","zip","county_name"];

const somePopulated = objProps.some(prop => obj[prop]);
// or prop => obj[prop] !== ''
console.log(somePopulated);
```